# How do screens display decimal point pixel values?

Tags: css, rendering, screen

What happens on a screen when I set this style?

```
styled-element {
  margin-top: 7.5px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}
```

What happens to the missing 0.5px? And how is it even possible to display less than 1px if the screen is not scaled somehow?

If you have a resolution of 1920x1080 aren´t there 1920 pixels at width and 1080 pixels at height?

I do not need to know the scientifically correct answer, I just would like to know if

```
styled-element-2 {
  margin-top: 7.5px;
  margin-bottom: 7.5px;
}
```

really showed 7.5px at top and bottom or if it does somehow shrink/expand the content in between by 1px whilst adding/removing 1px from the overall margin.

Answer (score -1):

Decimal value in px unit works.

- If you apply 7.5px it will 7px + 0.5px
- also if you apply 7.4px then it will be only 7px
- if you apply 7.6px then it will be 8px
  less then 5 will goes to nearest lowest value and greater then 5 will go to nearest upper value

Comment: The real question is, can you render half a pixel?